# Is there a word to designate people enforcing that nobody is poaching at sea

Tags: single-word-requests

*Coastguards* are an organization created for maritime security.

What I am looking for is a more precise word to designate the organization whose role is to enforce that fishing boats don't fish forbidden resources and respect fishing quotas.

Does this word exist? Is *coastguards* a good replacement?

Comment: In the United States, this agency is called the [National Marine Fisheries Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Marine_Fisheries_Service), and I believe other nations have a similar agency, with names similar to Fisheries Service or Ministry or Bureau or ...

Comment: Thanks, but is there a particular word for these agencies ?

Comment: Why do you think there has to be a single word?  Why does "fisheries agency" (two words) not satisfy?

Comment: I don't think there has to be a single word. I just would like to know if a one-word solution exists, and the answer seems to be "no".

Answer (score 1):

The Royal Navy has a specialised unit called the '**Fishery Protection** Squad'.

> The Fishery Protection Squadron is a front-line squadron of the Royal Navy with responsibility for patrolling the UK's Extended Fisheries Zone. The squadron, with headquarters at Portsmouth Naval Base, are equipped with four River-class patrol vessels; three are based in the UK, while HMS Clyde is based in the Falkland Islands.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishery_Protection_Squadron)

[image]